# How to compress images using blitline and save to amazon-s3 server

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using s3 server and blitline in my project and i want to compress images using blitline and save them to s3 server.

I have downloaded blitline java api but i am unable to run this api in my eclipse.

Can anyone please give me some suggestions to run this api.

Here is api link..   https://github.com/chrylis/blitline-java-client/tree/master/blitline-image-client

Comment: If you read the documentation on that, you'll see that I included runnable examples for both standalone operation and use with Spring.

Comment: can you give me link?

Comment: https://github.com/chrylis/blitline-java-client/tree/master/blitline-image-client

Comment: I have downloaded this project but i am unable to run... i import this project in eclipse but how can i run this project on localhost

Comment: i am getting this error... java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException